# Too many calls from DataGrid to ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF application what contains wpf toolkit datagrid.

Here is XAML code of DataGrid control

```
<wpf_toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Plans, Mode=OneTime}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PlanDataGrid" ColumnWidth="auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
     <wpf_toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <wpf_toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Key Note Name" IsReadOnly="True"
                       Binding="{Binding Path=KeyNotepad, Mode=OneTime}" />
        <wpf_toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="SKO Name" IsReadOnly="True"
                       Binding="{Binding Path=SKOName, Mode=OneTime}" />
        <wpf_toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="SKO Version" IsReadOnly="True"
                       Binding="{Binding Path=SKOVer, Mode=OneTime}" />
                      <-- Other 10 columns with data templates, bindings etc. -->
     </wpf_toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
 </wpf_toolkit:DataGrid>
```

ItemsSource property of DataGrid binds to collection of simple string-based view models.

So, the problem is that DataGrid takes data from items source columns_count * visible_rows_count times (about 27*13 times) what makes terrible application brakings.

Is there any way to reduce number of calls from DataGrid to items source?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem that i see is that row virtualization is not enabled. That causes DataGrid to create visual elements for all items in ItemsSource, not only those that are visible.
To enable virtualization you need to set this properties on DataGrid

```
EnableRowVirtualization="True"
```

And just to be on the safe side you need to set attached properties from VirtualizingStackPanel

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

VirtualizationMode will cause the DataGrid to reuse visual rows instead of generating new each time you scroll around. Though I'm not sure this is available to you since it looks like you're using WpfToolkit. Are you targetting .NET 3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. Yes. I work with .NET 3.5. I've made controls what contains datagrid static, so some loads ends at applications start. But, when I scroll DataGrid, it loads data, but not so much as at the first time.  Some words about virtualization. Data source that binds to DataGrid works like data virtualization container.

Here is link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization. 
My Data Source is similas. Also, I create style for grids, that enable virtualization and link in to datagrid (I forgot to write it in code sample here). But nothing changes. Here is my style and how I link it to DataGrid

```
<Style x:Key="vd_datagrid_style" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type wpf_toolkit:DataGrid}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type wpf_toolkit:DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
</Style>

<wpf_toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Plans, Mode=OneTime}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PlanDataGrid"
                                  Style="{StaticResource vd_datagrid_style}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlan, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Hmm... I'll try to add EnableRowVirtualization="True" to my style.

P.S. Is there any way to check whether the style is connected to the control?